# common file to be translated for python program and a Django app

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I need to use a set of constants in both a Django application and a Python program. These constants include a string to translate.
I defined these constants in a separate file named **constants.py:**

```
E6000_Stitch_Tech_RANGES_TYPES = ( 
    ('CO', _ ('Cast_On'), (1,15)),
    ('BA', _ ('basic point no grid pattern'), (100,122)), 
    ('TK', _ ('Tuck stitch'),(129,175)),
    )
```

In my python program I `import gettext` and the `'_'` seems to be recognized.

In my **Django models** I do :

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from .constants import E6000_Stitch_Tech_RANGES_TYPES as RANGES_TYPES
```

and I get the following **error message** :

```
 ('CO', _ ('Cast_On'), (1,15)),
NameError: name '_' is not defined.
```

Any solution?

Comment: You do that in your models, but do you import these in your `constants.py` as well?

Answer (score 0):

> In my Django **models** I do:
>
> ```
> from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
> from .constants import E6000_Stitch_Tech_RANGES_TYPES as RANGES_TYPES
> ```

If I understand it correctly, you did *not* import the function in your constants. That means that the name `_` is undefined in the *scope* of `constants.py`. Yes it is defined in `models.py`, but that is a *different* scope. If the call is interpreted, and this is done in the scope of that file, it thus can not find the reference.

You thus need to do the import in the `constants.py` file itself, like:

```
# app/constants.py

# you need to import this in constants.py if you make the calls in constants.py
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

E6000_Stitch_Tech_RANGES_TYPES = ( 
    ('CO', _ ('Cast_On'), (1,15)),
    ('BA', _ ('basic point no grid pattern'), (100,122)), 
    ('TK', _ ('Tuck stitch'),(129,175)),
)
```